# Python Class With Lots of Variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, variables

What is the easiest way to define a class with 40 or more variables in Python?

Python 3.8 on Windows 10 is used.

```
class ExampleClass:
   def __init__(self, val_1 , val_2, .....40 variables):
       self.val_1 = val_1 
       self.val_2 = val_2
       .
       .
       40 variables
       .
       self.val_40 = val_40

   def example_function(self):
       #function code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, just type in their defaults in the class `__init__` as usual. You'll be typing these variable names throughout the program (otherwise, why are they there?) so its not much more work to do it. Sometimes lists and dictionaries are better choices, but there's no way we'd know for this case.

After your update showing 40 variables in `__init__`, you could allow any number of variables on init, make sure it meets your criteria (here I require exactly 40) and put them in a list.

```
class ExampleClass:
    def __init__(self, *vals):
        """Example(val1, ... val40)"""
        if len(vals) != 40:
            raise ValueError(f"Need 40 variables, got {len(vals)}")
        self.vals = list(vals)

   def example_function(self):
       # now using val_1 is 
       print(self.vals[0])
```

The thing about variables named "val_0" to "val_40" is that it really sounds listish. But whether a list is a good idea depends on how you want to use them later. If you really want to address them individually as `somevariable.val_0`, etc... then your existing example is the best way to do it.

Comment: I have updated the question. Is this the same thing with your answer?

Comment: @oduncu90 - if you want to address the variables individuallly later, it is the best way. If you do something like `obj.val_1 + obj.val_2 + ...` then you really wanted them to  be a list where you could do `sum(ovj.vals)` instead. Its a design choice based on intended use.

Comment: @oduncu90 - sorry, no. I don't use Windows often and am not up to date on whether you'd need a build environment for this. Maybe there is somebody out there doing prebuilt MSI's for these. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using namedtupled from `collections` build-in module as base class, but you have to override `__new__` which is called implicitly before `__init__`:

```
from collections import namedtuple
vars = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
BaseClass = namedtuple("MyClass", vars)

class MyClass(BaseClass):
    def __new__(cls, **inputs):
        self = super(MyClass, cls).__new__(cls, **inputs)
        return self

    def my_func_1(self):
        return self.a + self.b + self.c
    
    def my_func_2(self):
        return 3 * self.d 

obj = MyClass(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4)
print(obj.my_func_1())

# output
# 6
```

Even if you have the data into a dict, you can use doble asterisk for creating an object:

```
data = {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3, "d":4}
obj = MyClass(**data)
```